# Android - Links in TextView are not highlighted when clicked if embeded in DrawerLayout

Tags: android, textview, navigation-drawer

My App is based on the default Navigation Drawer Activity you can choose when creating a new Android Application in Eclipse.
The main fragment I created contains a TextView with autoLink. Android recognises links and they are blue colored and underlined, but when I tap/click on this link it is not highlighted and so the user gets no response that he hit the link and not missed it. In a simple App with only a TextView it works and when the user tap on the link it is highlighted for a short period of time before Android opens the link in Chrome. The hightlighting looks like this:
[image: screenshot with highlighted link in TextView]

So, I did some research why my links are not highlighted and removed all unnessesary things from my app. Now i can say that it only does not work like expected, when the `TextView` is embeded in a `DrawerLayout`.

This is now my stripped app, where you can easy reproduce my problem:

activity_mail.xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/simple_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:linksClickable="true"
            android:autoLink="all"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Test link: http://www.google.de. Test test testtest." />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.testlinktextview;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity  {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

When I replace the `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout` in the activity_main.xml with `LinearLayout` it works like expected.

Has anyone an idea how to get the links highlighted when clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/12047372/3271972 i found a solution.
... not a perfect solution, a little bit workaround, but maybe it is helpful for someone.

If you have a better solution i would be glad to read it.

I added to the TextView:

```
<TextView
...
     android:textColorLink="@color/link_selector"
```

and the new File link_selector.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#34b5e5" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="#34b5e5" />
    <item android:color="#35b5e5" />
</selector>
```

I think `#34b5e5` is nearly the original link color.
It is **very important** that the default color on the third item `<item android:color="#35b5e5" />` differs from the color in `state_pressed`. If they are the same, the links are still not highlighted when pressed! The colors must differ, even if only a little bit!

Comment: it works. But it is still strange, why its not working by default. I searched Google but there is too little info about links in TextView.